# Running same LINQ query on host machine very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My customer has issue that, he can't use 2 functions on my system because the operation is timeout.

So i ask him for DB backup to restore on my dev machine for test. On dev machine it run very quickly, no timeout.

My system is using EF to connect to DB.

First function run on my dev machine is less than 1 second, but on customer's server is timeout(for this function, timeout is set to 30 seconds).

Second function run on my dev machine is about 60 seconds, but on customer's server is timeout(for this function, timeout is set to 300 seconds).

I have test by using 'SQL Server Profiler' to capture statement that sent to SQL Server, then i send the captured statement by using SqlCommand instead, it's not slow, time usage is nearly to my dev machine.

I don't know why, is there any mistake configuration can make this thing happen.

Any ideas, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Three things I can think of to try:

1. If you are restoring to a newer version of SQL then your statistics are being updated when you restore. Have the customer run [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) on the tables that are being hit.
2. Take a look at the server specs, and task manager -> Resource Monitor see if anything jumps out at you.
3. It may be something environmental on their network. Check the network throughput between the client and server.